# Filter functionality in MS Graph Delta with OneDrive

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

How can I use the filter in the IDriveItemDeltaRequest correctly with C# and ASP.NET Core?

The interface says the following about filters

```
    // Adds the specified filter value to the request.
    //
    //   value:
    //     The filter value.
    //
    //     The request object to send.
    IDriveItemDeltaRequest Filter(string value);
```

I thought it was not possible to filter with Graph delta using Onedrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request), $filter is not supported. This method supports the $select, $expand, and $top OData query parameters to customize the response.

Being said that, consider filing [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so that same could be considered for future implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what is the filter actually good for?